# Update needs to be seen outside of transaction (Synchronization issue)

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions

I am working on a web project in PHP where a user clicks the "Reload" button, and a long running process is kicked off.

What I want to happen is that if one user is already running this process, then other users can tell when they load the page the process is already running, what time it started, and who started it. They should not be able to start the process again when it is already running.

I could do something like this (SQL below is simplified):

```
-- Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SELECT 1 FROM institutions WHERE institution_code = '15'  FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE institutions SET process_start = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
   process_acct_id = 101, process_finish = null WHERE institution_code = '15';

-- Process Runs here, taking a couple of hours.

UPDATE institutions SET process_finish = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
   WHERE institution_code = '15';

COMMIT;
```

The problem with the above is that other threads can't see the process_acct_id, process_start, and process_finish until after the process has run and the transaction has committed.  How do I write it so that they can? Do I run the first update in an autonomous transaction?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you give more detail about how that would be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Oracle so the syntax could not be the right one, but I will go for one only operation in the transaction. I have used an "Active" column instead of the timestamps to simplify it but you can work out a similar logic by using your timestamps. Also I have assumed you identify the actions by insititution code.

```
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE Active = 1 WHERE Active = 0 AND insititution_code = @InstitutionCode

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
BEGIN
   RETURN 0
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   RETURN 1
END

COMMIT
```

The point here is that the Update will block other transactions and the block of code will return 1 if has managed to update the row or 0 otherwise. You can then add your logic around that, knowing that the one that was successful to set the flag to 1 is the only one running.

This approach has the drawback that if you forget or fail to set the flag to 0 at the end other processes won't be able to run for that activity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit after you do your first update, but you also then need that update to check the process ID isn't already set - so a second caller stops at that point. If you can do this with several statements issued from your PHP layer then the outline would be:

```
UPDATE institutions
SET process_acct_id = 101,
  process_start = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  process_finish = null
WHERE institution_code = '15'
AND process_acct_id IS NULL; -- so no rows will be updated if a process is running

-- In PHP layer, check how may rows were updated (like SQL%ROWCOUNT)
-- If zero then another process is already running, so stop
-- With two simultaneous calls this will block briefly for the second call,
-- until the first commits when it sees row count of 1

COMMIT;

-- Other sessions now see process ID and start time
-- Process Runs here, taking a couple of hours.

UPDATE institutions
SET process_acct_id = null,
  process_finish = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
WHERE institution_code = '15';

COMMIT;
```